# How to get a dialog box back to front?

Tags: gui, window-management, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and experienced a problem with dialogs that don't have a "representation" in the task switch menu.

for instance, when I start Eclipse Luna (Kepler is working) and switch to another task before I choose a workspace in the workspace selection dialog that appears right after the splash screen, I cannot switch back to it. The workspace selection dialog doesn't appear in the task selection when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is there something like a console command that I can use to get it back in the foreground?

Something like `fg` for window applications?

Comment: No one? Really, I think there must be a way to catch a a window and put into the foreground again?

Comment: 1) you can minimize all other windows. 2) you can using alt-tab select eclipse and that workspace selection dialog should appear. 3) you may try using some tools like `devispie` but i think there is no point of doing that.

Comment: 1) Nope, not working. The dialog is "gone", after pressing Alt+Tab. This is, why 2) won't work, too. There's just nothing to Alt+Tab to. 
I just realized, that this just happens while starting Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution as of today with the help of a friendly colleague.

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> results in an overview of all open windows. The "missing" window is then one of it.